# Django-rest: show non-primary key field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Likely this will be a duplicate, but I can't seem to find anything as there's a no useful keywords.

manufacturer is a foreign key in car:

```
class manufacturer(models.Models):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=64)

class cars(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=64)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer')
```

Right now, I have a car api serialized to all fields it contains (id, name, manufacturer). However, the "manufacturer" field  shows the ID of the Manufacturer class.

***Question: How do I show the name of the manufacturer in the API for car and not the ID of the manufacturer?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a lot of experience with `django-rest-framework` but it looks like you need to [create a serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization) which will customize the converting of your object to JSON ready to return to the user so that the relationship is taken into account.

Put this in `manufacture_app/serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CarsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    manufacturer_name = serializers.RelatedField(source='manufacturer') 

    class Meta:
        model = Cars
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'manufacturer_name')
```

and make sure your `__unicode__` function returns the correct name:

```
class Manufacturer(models.Models):
    ....

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm having a hard time understanding the documentation. Do you have any advice on learning Django/Rest? It's my first time learning web development too.

Comment: Why isn't there a change in the models to describe the relationship?